# Overfitting in LSTM even after using regularizers

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am having a time series prediction problem and building an LSTM like below :

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01), input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.591))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

When I train the model on 5 splits like below :

```
tss = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 5)
X = data.drop(labels=['target_prediction'], axis=1)
y = data['target_prediction'] 
for train_index, test_index in tss.split(X):
   train_X, test_X = X.iloc[train_index, :].values, X.iloc[test_index,:].values
   train_y, test_y = y.iloc[train_index].values, y.iloc[test_index].values
   model=create_model()
   history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=64,validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=0, shuffle=False)
```

I get an overfitting problem. The graph of loss is attached [image]

I am not sure why there is overfitting when I use regularizers in my Keras model. Any help is appreciated .

**EDIT:**
Tried the architectures

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model


def create_model(x,y):
    # define LSTM
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(x,y)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

but still it is overfitting.

Comment: If you use a model for multilabel classification, I recommend you use 0.5 dropout, and if your data is binary, I recommend you use 0.2 dropout.

Comment: However, dropout is mostly used for CNN not LSTM.  So it is better to keep just kernel_regularizer, recurrent_regularizer, and bias_regularizer. One other thing, you can change your learning rate to prevent overfitting, for example, check learning_rate = 2e-5 in Adam algorithm.

Answer (score 10):

First of all remove all your regularizers and dropout. You are literally spamming with all the tricks out there and 0.5 dropout is too high.

Reduce the number of units in your LSTM. Start from there. Reach a point where your model stops overfitting.

Then, add dropout if required.

After that, the next step is to add the `tf.keras.Bidirectional`. If still, you are not satfisfied then, increase number of layers. Remember to keep `return_sequences` True for every LSTM layer except the last one.

It is seldom I come across networks using layer regularization despite the availability because dropout and layer regularization have a same effect and people usually go with dropout (at maximum, I have seen 0.3 being used).

Comment: @Used a simple architecture with fewer units and no dropout still overfits